# syntax error: unterminated quoted string Docker Certbot

Tags: docker, shell, nginx, docker-compose, certbot

I'm using docker compose. I'm working with a nextjs project. The focus here is setting up the containers specifically to automate server configuration, including SSL certification using Certbot. My objectives are to first get the initial certificate then run a cron job to check if it needs to be renewed. This is a learning exercise for me and would appreciate any insight into my knowledge gap, thank you. I have this docker-compose.yml and the error seems to originate from the Certbot entrypoint. There is no other Certbot configuration beyond this script. Could something else in the container be causing the error? I wasn't able to get the container up and running because it would crash with the error. I don't see any unterminated quoted string.

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        NODE_ENV: production
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app/src
      - ./public:/app/public
      - /app/node_modules
    container_name: nextjs

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    environment:
      - DOMAIN_NAMES=${DOCKER_DOMAIN_NAMES}
      - CERTIFICATION_EMAIL=${DOCKER_CERTIFICATION_EMAIL}
    volumes:
      - ./ssl-dhparams.pem:/etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf.template:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf.template:ro
      - ./nginx/options-ssl-nginx.conf:/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf:ro
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    depends_on:
      - app
  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot
    entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c 'echo \"0 */12 * * * certbot renew --webroot -w /var/www/certbot --quiet --post-hook 'nginx -s reload'\" | crontab - && crond -f'"
    volumes:
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    depends_on:
      - nginx
```

Unfortunately I reached the rate limit with letsencrypt, but it will expire tomorrow so I can try again. In the mean time I'm trying to figure out what I did wrong and if there's a better way to do it. So far I came up with this alternative to instead replace entrypoint with command and use a shell script to check if https is available and if it fails then run a renewal:

```
  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot
    command: certonly --webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/certbot --email ${DOCKER_CERTIFICATION_EMAIL} --agree-tos --no-eff-email --staging --domains ${DOCKER_DOMAIN_NAMES} --non-interactive
    entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c 'chmod +x /scripts/cert_renewal.sh && /scripts/cert_renewal.sh && crond -f'"
    volumes:
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
      - ./nginx:/scripts
    depends_on:
      - nginx
```

and this would be the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

DOMAIN_NAME="www.mydomainhere.com"
WEBROOT_PATH="/var/www/certbot"

# Check if the HTTPS site is available
if ! curl --head --silent --fail https://${DOMAIN_NAME}; then
    echo "HTTPS site is not available, running Certbot renewal"
    certbot renew --webroot -w ${WEBROOT_PATH} --quiet --post-hook 'nginx -s reload'
fi

# Add this script to crontab if it's not already there
if ! crontab -l | grep -q "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"; then
    (crontab -l ; echo "0 */12 * * * ${BASH_SOURCE[0]}") | crontab -
    echo "Added Certbot renewal to crontab"
fi
```

Any suggestions? Thoughts? What am I doing wrong? Please leave some input, thank you.

Comment: "Unfortunately I reached the rate limit with letsencrypt": Note that Lets Encrypt has a staging server without rate limits that you can use for testing.

Comment: @larsks yes, thank you. I did come across that recently and will try to use the staging server until I get this figured out.

Comment: _entrypoint_ starts with the quotes string `"/bin/sh -c 'echo \"`, then comes a lot of unquoted parts, and then comes another quotes string `'nginx -s reload'`. The following double-quote is escaped and does not count.  After a few more unquoted parts, the line ends with a `'"`, which means that you open a single-quote which is not closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are certainly some quoting problems in your certbot entrypoint; you have nested single quotes that result in the arguments to `--post-hook` being *outside* of the single quotes that enclose your `sh -c '...'` invocation. Pasting the command line into https://www.shellcheck.net/ would help identify those issues.

You can avoid a level of quoting -- and minimize the necessity of escaping quotes -- by taking advantage of (a) the list form the of the entrypoint command and (b) YAML's block quote operators. If you rewrite the entrypoint like this:

```
entrypoint:
  - /bin/sh
  - -c
  - |
    echo "0 */12 * * * certbot renew --webroot -w /var/www/certbot --quiet --post-hook 'nginx -s reload'" |
      crontab - && crond -f
```

Things are a bit more clear and only require a single level of quoting.

Comment: what about my idea to run a separate script in the container? what do you think is the best approach here? I'm not familiar with how certbot does everything and want to avoid hitting the rate limit especially since my current deployment script is going to rebuild my docker containers each time a commit happens.

Comment: As long as you're preserving certbot's state information outside of the container (e.g., in a Docker volume), certbot won't make requests to the letsencrypt API unless a certificate needs to be renewed...but that seems like a different question than the one you asked, which was primarily about a shell syntax issue. You may want to open a new question if you have questions that are specific to certbot.